# Jquery li position returns zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a simple list where some of the elements have class "parent"

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="parent">text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li class=parent>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**div** has `text-align:justify;`, **ul** has `position:relative;`, **li** has `display: inline-block; position:relative;`

I use the following code to get position of every li with class 'parent'. Then i want to add class to some of them, which position is less than 100.

```
var position = $('.parent').position();

if (position.left < 100) {
    $('.parent').addClass('left');
}
```

But it always returns zero at `.position()` step (probably position of the first `.parent`?)

How can I make it work properly and make every li with class return the right position?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krish/Denzu/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filter elements based on position, and add class :

```
$('.parent').filter(function() {
   return $(this).position().left < 100;
}).addClass('left');
```

Comment: Perfect! Live long and prosper, clever person.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, its grabbing the position of the first parent.

You can do something like this

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).position().left < 100 )
         $(this).addClass('left');
});
```

Comment: Fiddle have a bug `class=parent`

Comment: Yep, adeneo has the fix! I removed the fiddle, as it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Can use callback of `addClass`

```
$('.parent').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).posiition().left <100 ?'left':'';
})
```

The problem with your approach using `var position = $('.parent').position();` is it will only return the value for the first element in the collection, not for each instance of the selector